# How to use python kafka client with gevent - is there a libary that actually works?

Tags: python, python-2.7, gevent, apache-kafka

I am trying to use gevent to write to kafka 0.7.2 using brod on python 2.7.

Here is the error message I get.  Guess its due to blocking.  brod supports tornado but I use gevent.

```
No handlers could be found for logger "brod.socket"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/chef/cache/src/gevent/gevent/greenlet.py", line 328, in run
    result = self._run(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "worker_server.py", line 204, in execute_kafka_pipe
    kafka.produce(topic,payload)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/brod-0.3.2-py2.7.egg/brod/base.py", line 287, in produce
    return self._write(request, callback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/brod-0.3.2-py2.7.egg/brod/blocking.py", line 98, in _write
    return self._write(data, callback, retries)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/brod-0.3.2-py2.7.egg/brod/blocking.py", line 89, in _write
    wrote_length += self._socket.send(data)
  File "/var/chef/cache/src/gevent/gevent/socket.py", line 441, in send
    self._wait(self._write_event)
  File "/var/chef/cache/src/gevent/gevent/socket.py", line 292, in _wait
    assert watcher.callback is None, 'This socket is already used by another greenlet: %r' % (watcher.callback, )
AssertionError: This socket is already used by another greenlet: <bound method Waiter.switch of <gevent.hub.Waiter object at 0x1dece60>>
<Greenlet at 0x1d4b9b0: execute_kafka_pipe('topic-spend', '{"enode": 1, "city": "Cairns", "dl": "en", "wnode)> failed with AssertionError
```

I tried to use gevent-kakfa but depends on  gevent-zookeeper.

When trying to connect to zookeeper i get this message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/rtbhui-devops/servers/worker_server.py", line 68, in <module>
    framework = gevent_zookeeper.ZookeeperFramework('localhost:2181', 10)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gevent_zookeeper/framework.py", line 241, in __init__
    self.client = ZookeeperClient(hosts, timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gevent_zookeeper/client.py", line 211, in __init__
    self._event = gevent.core.event(
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'core'
Exception AttributeError: "'ZookeeperClient' object has no attribute '_event'" in <bound method ZookeeperClient.__del__ of <gevent_zookeeper.client.ZookeeperClient object at 0x274ded0>> ignored
```

Is there not a python lib that I can I write messages using gevent that works?

Comment: I was looking for the same and came across this https://github.com/duanhongyi/kafka. Since I haven't tried it myself, I'm noting it here rather than as an answer.

Comment: Also, https://github.com/mahendra/kafka-python/tree/gevent claims to have it working but has not yet submitted a pull request to the original kafka-python b/c it depends upon another pull request being merged first.

Comment: If you find a lib that works with kafka 8 and gevnet ..please let me know but will try the link above

Comment: I've been in touch with the with the author of the tree/gevent branch and he says it passes all tests... and he's willing to help if there's any problems.

Comment: Found working solution yet ?

Answer (score 2):

You might try https://github.com/hmahmood/kafka-python/tree/gevent-impl

which is currently submitted for PR to the mainline kafka-python library:

https://github.com/mumrah/kafka-python/pull/145

Comment: [The PR has been closed](https://github.com/mumrah/kafka-python/pull/145#issuecomment-39772915). The author says it's easier to use [gevent.monkey](http://www.gevent.org/gevent.monkey.html). There seems to have been some problems with both `KafkaConnection` and `KafkaClient`, however, but they were supposed to be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Pykafka](http://pykafka.readthedocs.io)

Although you should be able to configure kafka-python by passing in the [selector](http://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/apidoc/KafkaConsumer.html) used by gevent